# Chartview crashing in QML

Tags: qml, qtquick2

My chartview is crashing in QML - QT Quick application.

This is how my chartview looks like:

```js
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtCharts 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    GridView
    {
        ChartView {
            title: "Spline"
            anchors.fill: parent
            antialiasing: true

            SplineSeries {
                name: "SplineSeries"
                XYPoint { x: 0; y: 0.0 }
                XYPoint { x: 1.1; y: 3.2 }
                XYPoint { x: 1.9; y: 2.4 }
                XYPoint { x: 2.1; y: 2.1 }
                XYPoint { x: 2.9; y: 2.6 }
                XYPoint { x: 3.4; y: 2.3 }
                XYPoint { x: 4.1; y: 3.1 }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is crashing and not able to launch window

Comment: Your items probably are zero-sided, you have to give some size

Comment: I am new to QT, Can you paste the code snippet for the same ?

Answer (score 1):

Probably, the segmentation fault is because you need to replace in your main function the `QGuiApplication` by `QApplication`. More [info](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-qmlmodule.html).

The following code is working properly:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtCharts 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    Rectangle {
        width: 300
        height: 300
        ChartView {
            title: "Spline"
            anchors.fill: parent
            antialiasing: true

            SplineSeries {
                name: "SplineSeries"

                XYPoint { x: 0; y: 0.0 }
                XYPoint { x: 1.1; y: 3.2 }
                XYPoint { x: 1.9; y: 2.4 }
                XYPoint { x: 2.1; y: 2.1 }
                XYPoint { x: 2.9; y: 2.6 }
                XYPoint { x: 3.4; y: 2.3 }
                XYPoint { x: 4.1; y: 3.1 }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Tarod , Thanks for response. I am trying the chartview in QtQuick application .

Comment: Can you please help me how to make chart view work in QTQuick applications

Comment: Did you try my solution? It's working good.

Comment: You have the complete example here: https://github.com/ftena/qt-snippets/tree/master/qml-chartview It's important to add `widgets` to the line `QT += qml quick gui widgets` in your .pro file.